# ffmpeg resize large image and high resolution

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

I tried to resize a very big image (457 MB and 21600x21600) with the following command

`-i test.png -vf scale=320:-1 out.png`

but it throws exception saying "Picture size 21600x21600 is invalid". How can I find out the biggest supported resolution by ffmpeg? Is there a way to resize this high resolution image with ffmpeg?

Comment: Maybe your PNG is poorly formed... try `pngcheck -v test.png`

Comment: I am getting the same error message. Consider using other software for the job.

Comment: According to following post: [https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21000/largest-input-image-size-when-encoding-a-video](Largest input image size when encoding a video?), It looks like maximum supported resolution is about `16384x16384`.

Comment: @Rotem do you have any suggestion for such software?

Comment: Personally, I use MATLAB. In case there are only few images, you can use paint.net or GIMP... For mass conversion, you can try [https://imagemagick.org/index.php](ImageMagick). I don't know if ImageMagick supports high resolution, and if resize quality is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use **ImageMagick** it is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Your command becomes:

```
convert test.png -resize 320x result.png
```

If you are running v7 or newer, use:

```
magick test.png -resize 320x result.png
```

---

If you have lots to do, and you want all the resized images written in a directory called `thumbs` you can use:

```
mkdir thumbs
magick mogrify -path thumbs -resize 320x *.png
```

---

Alternatively, you may find `vips` is a lighter-weight installation and does a faster conversion using less memory:

```
mkdir thumbs
vipsthumbnail -s 320 -o "thumbs/%s.png" image.png
```